# Uploading files with node.js (using package panxapi)

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to upload files using the [panxapi](https://github.com/rsolomo/panxapi.js)?

For example an API call requires a file upload for setting a user-ip mapping.

In curl this done with

```
curl -form file=@myfile "https://hostname/api/?type=user-id&action=set"
```

I'm unsure how to add this as a parameter to my API call using panxapi.

Heres my code:

```
var panxapi = require('panxapi');

// Connect to the client
var client = panxapi.createPanClient({
    host: 'hostname',
    key: 'apikey',
    protocol: 'https'
});

var params = {
    type: 'user-id',
    action: 'set',
}

client.request(params, function(err, xml, etree) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(xml);
})
```

And the curl call (that works)

```
curl --form file=@ipmapping "https://hostname/api/?type=user-id&action=set&key=<key>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding the functionality to the package. Forked [here](https://github.com/mjfreeman7/panxapi.js).